# How to use Conditional Compilation in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, win-universal-app

I'm using VS 2017 to implement an app that shares code between Windows form and Universal Windows App.

In project properties I see conditional compilation symbols as below:

[image: project properties]

When I use below code

```
#if WINDOWS_UWP
    // code for Windows Universal App
#else
    // code for Windows Form
#endif
```

program executes the Windows Form code not the UWP code.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try commas instead of semicolons?

Comment: This is the default setting. I haven't changed it. But I'll give it a try

Comment: Oh, huh. Well, I've never seen projects with anything in there by default, and some online sources showed screenshots with commas.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Was it a general UWP project?

Comment: @Bite, yes it is regular UWP I crated using default template in VS 2017

Comment: I created a UWP project and add the `#if WINDOWS_UWP #else #endif` section. There's no problem. It will execute the code in `#if WINDOWS_UWP` section.

Comment: @Bite, I think the difference is I am using a class library and I use the conditional symbol in a file inside the class library. My expectation was the class library will inherit the conditions from the calling exec, but looks like it does not. Do you have any idea about this situation?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?